# Как взять нужное свойство в обьекта?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Приходит объект, мне с него нужно получить его свойства , те что в allfilms, только не знаю как это нужно делать :
пробовал так :

```
 var test = projects.data.allfilms
```

но получается данные: `[rosdestvenskaya istoriya: object, sreck: object]`.  и т.д.

Как сделать чтоб было так: `["rosdestvenskaya istoriya", "sreck", "sauth parck"]`... и т.д.

```
var projects = [{
    "data": {
        "allfilms": {
            "rosdestvenskaya istoriya": {},
            "sreck": {},
            "lednikoviy period": {},
            "simsoni": {},
            "sauth parck": {},
            "rapuncel": {}
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Уважаемый, вы всю неделю ежедневно пишете достаточно простые, невнятно сформулированные, плохо оформленные вопросы. Пожалуйста, уделите немного больше внимания формулировке вопросов и собственным попыткам решить проблемы. 

Возможно, также, вам стоит уделить время систематизации знаний по разработке в данной области и прочитать что-нибудь из основополагающих книг по JS.

Comment: Мой комментарий больше обращает внимание на систематичную неаккуратность. Пример, приведённый вами, был некорректен и даже не выполнился бы. Вы спрашивали про allfilms, а в примере приводили поле allbrand. Объявление массива не закрыто, скобки вылазят за ограничение области кода, в тексте опечатки.

Comment: Вы правы , нужно больше времени уделять формулировке вопроса . Не правильно вас понял извините... Просто js ток начал изучать , до этого ток css и html, изучал... Насчёт литературы то изучаю learn.javascript. Дальше планиру Девида Флагма, хотя говорят, что для начала то она сложная...

Comment: За что же вы так "**Дэвида Флэнагана**" обижаете...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно перебрать ключи объекта, при этом добавив проверку на `hasOwnProperty` чтобы не включить унаследованные свойства случайно.

```
var test = [];

for(var k in projects.data.allfilms) { 
    if(projects.data.allfilms.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        test.push(k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если не нужна поддрежка старых браузеров, можно использовать [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(projects.data.allfilms);
```

А если все-таки нужна, можно использовать либо полифил либо, метод предложенный **@LbISS**.